# sizeof(double) is 8 one time, another 0?

Tags: c, debugging, linked-list, double, sizeof

I' wrote a linked-list lib for educating myself writing C and doing some stuff related to my Information-technology learning. 
I found out, that something went terrible wrong because of sizeof(double) was resolved to 0 for 4.9:

```
double ary[] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.5, 4.9, 5.5 };
LinkedList *list = linkedlist(&ary[0], sizeof(ary[0]));
for( i = 1; i<len(ary); i++ )
    ll_push(list, &ary[i], sizeof(double) );
```

(lines 267-270 in [this test](https://github.com/matthiasbeyer/utilc/blob/use_memcpy/tests/ll_test.c#L267) for [this library](https://github.com/matthiasbeyer/utilc/blob/use_memcpy/src/linkedlist/linkedlist.c))

Everything is fine for 1.0, 2.0 and 3.5, but for 4.9 it failes. Previous, I had sizeof(ary[i]) in the code, but now sizeof(double) results in the same way.

I'm really upset with this. Can anyone explain, why this happens?

Comment: Please don't call macros `len`, use upper case letters for macros, and a better name, `ARRAY_LENGTH` would be okay.

Comment: I will do so! Thank you!

Comment: What is actually happening?  `sizeof` is evaluated at compile-time, so your assumption about the problem can't be right.

Comment: you give irrelevant information in your question. Before asking here try to cook your problem down to something easily expressible and reproducible. Take the warnings that your compiler gives you into account... And also perhaps accept a little more of the previous questions.

Answer (score 7):

Aside from some irrelevant situations, `sizeof` is a compile-time entity, it is always "resolved" and replaced with the actual constant value at compile-time. Which immediately means that what you describe is completely impossible. `sizeof(ary[i])` cannot change its value depending on `i`. Both `sizeof(double)` and `sizeof(ary[i])` on your platform are always replaced with immediate `8` and do not depend on any run-time factors.

Whatever is wrong in your program has absolutely nothing to do with the behavior of `sizeof`. Your conclusion about `sizeof` somehow evaluating to `0` for `ary[3]` is incorrect. The fact that the version with `sizeof(double)` fails in exactly the same way should have been a clear hint to you.

Comment: as you can see, I wrote sizeof(double) in the Code and it behaves the same way as described.

Comment: Have you tried *printing* the value of `sizeof(double)`? You will see it never changes. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I've done this. It prints 8. Anyway, if I do some debugging and print the sizeof the current entry in the array, it's always 8.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has a good chance of working as you expect, when you fix all the compiler warnings:

cc **-Wall** -c ll_test.c

```
ll_test.c:67: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
ll_test.c:67: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
ll_test.c: In function 'test_dump':
ll_test.c:280: warning: format '%f' expects type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'double *'
ll_test.c:280: warning: format '%f' expects type 'double', but argument 3 has type 'double *'
ll_test.c: In function 'test_get_by_cond':
ll_test.c:295: warning: unused variable 'cmpList'
ll_test.c: In function 'test_datasize_of_last':
ll_test.c:422: warning: unused variable 'result'
ll_test.c: In function 'test_datasize_of_list':
ll_test.c:455: warning: unused variable 'result'
```

Pay particular attention to printf-formatting errors.